# Connecting to the terminal of a computer that is not connected to the Internet

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bluetooth, remote-access

I have two computers in my office, let's call them A and B. Computer A is connected to the internet and it has a bluetooth adapter, and I can connect to it via ssh. Computer B is not far from computer A, it also has a bluetooth adapter, but it is not connected to the Internet. I want to send commands to the terminal of computer B when I work from home (I have computer C through which I can connect to computer A via ssh). How can I do this? Is it possible to do this using bluetooth or other technologies?

Answer (score 1):

It is essential for the IP address of the target computer to be known, so ensure that it has a static address. I make all the IP addresses on your office static ones.

Then it is simple. Let’s assume your office router has the address 192.168.1.1, that your name is A machine and that you have user rights on the computers on your LAN.

For example, we will assume that the addresses and hostnames of two computers on your LAN are:

192.168.1.101 A machine Tom

192.168.1.102 B machine Jerry .

From a terminal on Tom to access Jerry, you could enter either:

$ ssh Tom@192.168.1.02 or

$ ssh Tom@Jerry

In both cases you will be asked for Tom password on Jerry.

Comment: The problem is that Computer A and computer B are on different connected to different routers =(

Comment: Unfortunately It's impossible then either same network or without internet connection.